# Prior distribution to the binomial distribution probability distributions urn model

Tags: r, distributions, probability, beta-binomial-distribution

I have an infinite population with unknown mean of successes and failures. I'm drawing 400 times from the population and get 400 successes. Now I want to generate random estimates for the true mean of the population from which I have drawn the 400 successes. Can anyone tell me which probability distribution I have to use, respectively how the function to use in R would look like?

I thought that

```
rbeta(1,400+1,400-400+1)
```

might be the right function, but even if I perform this one 10 000 000 times I never get the result 1 (and the same accounts for `rbeta(10000000,0+1,400-0+1)` and the result 0). So I ask myself why isn't it possible to have a population which consists only of successes or only of failures?

Comment: (1) Have you tried making some draws from a Beta distribution whose second parameter is close to $0$ and less than $1$?  *E.g.*, look at the output of `rbeta(10, 400.9, 0.1)`. (2) Suppose you draw a sample (with replacement) of size $10^{10}$ independently and at random from a population and that all results are successes. (This models the rising of the sun throughout the earth's total potential lifetime.) Are you *absolutely certain* that the population contains no failures??

Comment: The beta distribution will never generate a value of 1, as it is a continuous distribution and therefore the probability of generating any prespecified value (such as 1) is 0.  Are you sure you need to be able to generate an estimate of 1?  Or is your real objective to be able to generate a random "sample" of 400 1s based on an estimate derived from the real sample of 400 1s?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do, but my explanation of Bayesian inference on binomial data in this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/help-me-understand-bayesian-updating/44215#44215) might be useful.

Comment: @jb Please see my comment to Stéphane's answer.  The point is that there is an important difference between the Beta distribution as a mathematical object and that distribution as practically applied.  In effect, there *are* Beta distributions that will return zeros in simulations--and that's the setting of this question.

Comment: @whuber Ok, I learned, a beta distribution can return zero.

Comment: @jbowman Yes Your latter question is what I want to do: I want to generate a random "sample" of 400 1s based on an estimate derived from the real sample of 400 1s.

Answer (score 1):

I am under the impression your spirit is a little confused. You have to distinguish three things:

- the real experiment
- the mathematical (probabilistic/statistical) model for the real experiment
- the computational aspects of the statistical inference with the mathematical model

For the first point, you claim your population is infinite. So 1) there's no real experiment and your question is purely related to the mathematical model; or 2) you have a real experiment with a huge population and the consideration of an infinite population actually is an assumption of the model (a model can only approximate the real experiment).

You assume a Beta posterior distribution for the proportion of successes. This distribution is a mathematical object, it is a part of the mathematical modeling of your problem. Firstly, a Beta random variable never takes the value $0$ - this is a matter of probability theory; more rigorously we should say that it *almost* never equals $0$, but the "almost never" probabilistic notion aims to modelize the "never" notion in the real world. Secondly, you use a computer to generate a Beta variable: the numbers you generate are not random, but *pseudo-random*, and everything is done by the programmer in order that $0$ and $1$ will never be generated **(*)**.

Finally, I suggest you take a look at the probability to sample a success in your infinite population. To do so, you could use the Beta-binomial distribution available in the VGAM package or evaluate this probability using simulations:

```
> n <- 1000000
> sims <- rep(NA,n)
> for(i in 1:n){
+ p <- rbeta(1,401,1)
+ sims[i] <- rbinom(1,1,p)
+ }
> mean(x)
[1] 0.99754
```

It is not $1$, why ? Assume you sample $2$ individuals and you get $2$ successes in a population made of $10^6$ individuals. Would you infer that success occurs for every individual of the population ? So what about $400$ successes in an infinite population ?

**(*)** This point is wrong. See comments below. But for instance a computer never generates the values $0$ and $1$ for a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ask any computer to draw a random double precision value from a $B(10^{-6}, 1-10^{-6})$ distribution: I will give you thousand-to-one odds that it's zero.  (It would be a bad bet on your part. :-)

Comment: @whuber You're right, except that $10^{-6}$ is not small enough: R returns $0$ when generating $B(10^{-16}, 1-10^{-16})$.

Comment: An exact calculation will show that the odds of a double precision underflow (resulting in returning a zero) with $10^{-6}$ are about $1447$ to $1$ in favor. The difference between exponents of $-6$ and $-16$ is important, because in double precision $10^{-16}$ is essentially zero when compared to $1$, so you might be tempted to argue that the problem lies in imprecision in specifying the *parameters* of the distribution. No such argument is tenable when the parameters are $10^{-6}$ and $1-10^{-6}$.

Comment: @whuber: rbeta(1,1e-6,1-1e-6) generates 5.562685e-315

Comment: In double precision, that's a denormalized value considered equal to zero :-).

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent For the first point Your second assumption is right: I have a real experiment with a huge population and the consideration of an infinite population actually is an assumption of the model. In fact my question was related to the germination of seeds and I get Your's and whuber's point with the infinite population. This leads actually to the next question: What if I have a finite population of let's say 500 and I draw 400 times and get 400 successes. Wouldn't there be a chance that the real population just contains successes? How could I model this in R?

Comment: @PeterDeplewski Of course there's "a chance". But with a continuous prior distribution you will always get a zero probability. Note that here you should use the hypergeometric distribution, not the binomial one.

Comment: @whuber I believe you. I have never (tried to) understand what is double precision.

Comment: @PeterDeplewski Oops sorry here with the hypergeometric distribution the parameter space is discrete so there is a positive probability that the population contains successes only. Sorry I'm busy now.

Comment: Peter, in your 400/500 example you are seeking either a *Binomial confidence interval* for the number of successes or a (Bayesian) *credible interval* for that number. There are many good threads on this site about both (although I believe most focus on sampling with replacement, rather than sampling without replacement).

Comment: @whuber Why do you say "binomial" if the sampling is without replacement ? This rather hypergeometric, no ?

Comment: Thank you, Stéphane, for that clarifying remark: I cannot discern, from the information provided, whether a Binomial or Hypergeometric distribution is involved (it depends on the sampling method). But in either case, the OP appears to be asking for either a confidence interval or credible interval. That I would venture to point out something so obvious was inspired by your introductory paragraph, which (to me) suggests there may be some merit in clearing up any possible confusion about the distinctions between *population parameters* and *estimates made from data*.

Comment: @whuber In the 400/500 example I thought of a hypergeometric distribution and basically Your're right confidence intervals or credible intervals are appropiate for my question, just that I would prefer for my original simulation random samples based on the probabilities instead of confidence or credible intervals based on them. But I guess I will use for this now the rbeta function since the population size I assume originally is minimum 200000000.